# SQL query for retrieving numeric value and printing as words

Tags: sql

What will be the query for retrieving a number from a column of a table and printing it in words?
e.g:-data is 72
it should be printed as Seventy Two

Comment: that's something you should do with php/asp/jsp/python/etc.

Comment: And you can start voting up as well.

Answer (score 1):

No RDBMS I know of has such a function, and even though you could write one as a udf or sproc most DBs have abyssal string handling.  Do this in your client app.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same we are using in our project as well. There is no built-in method for this, but I have a function which you can try on your end. Hope this will help you - Ofcourse you can tweak for your requirements -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NumberToWords] 
(
    @NumberString nvarchar(max)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @Number Numeric (38, 0)
DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE (number CHAR(2), word VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @loops INT
DECLARE @position INT
DECLARE @chunk CHAR(3) 
DECLARE @tensones CHAR(2)
DECLARE @hundreds CHAR(1)
DECLARE @tens CHAR(1)
DECLARE @ones CHAR(1)

set @Number = cast( @NumberString as Numeric (38, 0) )

IF @Number = 0 Return 'Zero'

-- initialize the variables
SELECT @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number)
     , @outputString = ''
     , @counter = 1
SELECT @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)
     , @position = LEN(@inputNumber) - 2
     , @loops    = LEN(@inputNumber)/3

-- make sure there is an extra loop added for the remaining numbers
IF LEN(@inputNumber) % 3 <> 0 SET @loops = @loops + 1

-- insert data for the numbers and words
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable   SELECT '00', ''
    UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'one'      UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'two'
    UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'three'    UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'four'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'five'     UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'six'
    UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'seven'    UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'eight'
    UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'nine'     UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'ten'
    UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'eleven'   UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'twelve'
    UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'thirteen' UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'fourteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'fifteen'  UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'sixteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'seventeen' UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'eighteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'nineteen' UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'twenty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'thirty'   UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'forty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'fifty'    UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'sixty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'seventy'  UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'eighty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'ninety'   

WHILE @counter <= @loops BEGIN

    -- get chunks of 3 numbers at a time, padded with leading zeros
    SET @chunk = RIGHT('000' + SUBSTRING(@inputNumber, @position, 3), 3)

    IF @chunk <> '000' BEGIN
        SELECT @tensones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 2)
             , @hundreds = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, 1)
             , @tens = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 1)
             , @ones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 3, 1)

        -- If twenty or less, use the word directly from @NumbersTable
        IF CONVERT(INT, @tensones) <= 20 OR @Ones='0' 
        BEGIN
            SET @outputString = (SELECT word 
                                      FROM @NumbersTable 
                                      WHERE @tensones = number)
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                               + @outputString
            END
         ELSE BEGIN -- break down the ones and the tens separately

             SET @outputString = ' ' 
                            + (SELECT word 
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE @tens + '0' = number)
                             + '-'
                             + (SELECT word 
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE '0'+ @ones = number)
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                            + @outputString
        END

        -- now get the hundreds
        IF @hundreds <> '0' BEGIN
            SET @outputString  = (SELECT word 
                                      FROM @NumbersTable 
                                      WHERE '0' + @hundreds = number)
                                + ' hundred ' 
                                + @outputString
        END
    END

    SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
         , @position = @position - 3

END

SET @outputString = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')))
SET @outputstring = UPPER(LEFT(@outputstring, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@outputstring, 2, 8000)


RETURN @outputString
END
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like unreferenced code copied from the site I referenced in my post. A least give credit to your sources

Comment: Btw, this version of function is for SQL server.

Comment: @James Wiseman - We have this function written in our project and we are using this in our reports from past 1 year atleast.

Comment: @James Wiseman - Thanks buddy. I am visiting your link now actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built-in function, but this is a good starting point.

http://www.novicksoftware.com/udfofweek/Vol2/T-SQL-UDF-Vol-2-Num-9-udf_Num_ToWords.htm

Which flavour of SQL are we talking here?

That said, as you are efefctively tranforming the data, this is really something that shoudl be done in your business or even presentation layer

**EDIT**

Brilliant! Just tested it myself:

```
select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(19264235677575674234234234234223123123)
```

> Nineteen undecillion two hundred
>   sixty-four decillion two hundred
>   thirty-five nonillion six hundred
>   seventy-seven octillion five hundred
>   seventy-five septillion six hundred
>   seventy-four sextillion two hundred
>   thirty-four quintillion two hundred
>   thirty-four quadrillion two hundred
>   thirty-four trillion two hundred
>   thirty-four billion two hundred
>   twenty-three million one hundred
>   twenty-three thousand one hundred
>   twenty-three

:-)

SECOND EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENT

Modified the function to include 'and's:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (

    @Number Numeric (38, 0) -- Input number with as many as 18 digits

) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
/*
* Converts a integer number as large as 34 digits into the 
* equivalent words.  The first letter is capitalized.
*
* Attribution: Based on NumberToWords by Srinivas Sampath
*        as revised by Nick Barclay
*
* Example:
select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (1234567890) + CHAR(10)
      +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (0) + CHAR(10)
      +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (123) + CHAR(10)
select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(76543210987654321098765432109876543210)

DECLARE @i numeric (38,0)
SET @i = 0
WHILE @I <= 1000 BEGIN 
    PRINT convert (char(5), @i)  
            + convert(varchar(255), dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(@i)) 
    SET @I  = @i + 1 
END
*
* Published as the T-SQL UDF of the Week Vol 2 #9 2/17/03
****************************************************************/
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE (number CHAR(2), word VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @loops INT
DECLARE @position INT
DECLARE @chunk CHAR(3) -- for chunks of 3 numbers
DECLARE @tensones CHAR(2)
DECLARE @hundreds CHAR(1)
DECLARE @tens CHAR(1)
DECLARE @ones CHAR(1)
DECLARE @interim VARCHAR(8000)

IF @Number = 0 Return 'Zero'

-- initialize the variables
SELECT @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number)
     , @outputString = ''
     , @counter = 1
SELECT @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)
     , @position = LEN(@inputNumber) - 2
     , @loops    = LEN(@inputNumber)/3

-- make sure there is an extra loop added for the remaining numbers
IF LEN(@inputNumber) % 3 <> 0 SET @loops = @loops + 1

-- insert data for the numbers and words
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable   SELECT '00', ''
    UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'one'      UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'two'
    UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'three'    UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'four'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'five'     UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'six'
    UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'seven'    UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'eight'
    UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'nine'     UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'ten'
    UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'eleven'   UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'twelve'
    UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'thirteen' UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'fourteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'fifteen'  UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'sixteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'seventeen' UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'eighteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'nineteen' UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'twenty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'thirty'   UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'forty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'fifty'    UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'sixty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'seventy'  UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'eighty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'ninety'   

WHILE @counter <= @loops BEGIN

    -- get chunks of 3 numbers at a time, padded with leading zeros
    SET @chunk = RIGHT('000' + SUBSTRING(@inputNumber, @position, 3), 3)

    IF @chunk <> '000' BEGIN
        SELECT @tensones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 2)
             , @hundreds = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, 1)
             , @tens = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 1)
             , @ones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 3, 1)

        -- If twenty or less, use the word directly from @NumbersTable
        IF CONVERT(INT, @tensones) <= 20 OR @Ones='0' BEGIN
            SELECT @interim = word
              FROM @NumbersTable 
              WHERE @tensones = number

            if rtrim(ltrim(isnull(@interim,''))) <> ''
            begin
                set @interim = 'and ' + @interim
            end     

            SET @outputString = @interim
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                               + @outputString
            END
         ELSE BEGIN -- break down the ones and the tens separately

             SET @outputString = ' ' 
                            + (SELECT 'and ' + isnull(word,'')
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE @tens + '0' = number)
                             + '-'
                             + (SELECT word 
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE '0'+ @ones = number)
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                            + @outputString
        END

        -- now get the hundreds
        IF @hundreds <> '0' BEGIN
            SET @outputString  = (SELECT word 
                                      FROM @NumbersTable 
                                      WHERE '0' + @hundreds = number)
                                + ' hundred ' 
                                + @outputString
        END
    END

    SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
         , @position = @position - 3

END

-- Remove any double spaces
SET @outputString = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')))
SET @outputstring = UPPER(LEFT(@outputstring, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@outputstring, 2, 8000)


RETURN @outputString -- return the result
END
```

Comment: Very nice, but for some of us, it should be "one hundred _AND_ twenty-three" >;-)

Comment: Yeah noticed that. Have updated accordingly (see second edit!)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do this by creating a permananet table and populating it with the number and the words. I don't know how large you need to go with this, but inserting the words once into a table (it's not like they are going to change) woudl be far more efficient than using a function to determine the words. If you need need to go into the millions with this (or higher) you could create script to generate the data for the table using the functions above as a starting place.

If you intend to do this transformation frequently, a table with good indexing that you can join to would be the best performing method.